# How to show multiple exit conditions in a system sequence diagram loop frame

Tags: sequence-diagram, system

How are multiple exit conditions in a system sequence diagram loop frame indicated? And how would the alternative event flow based on how the system exited the loop be shown?
For example a login loop could exit after a valid login or after a set number of failed login attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably going to look similar to this:

[image]

See how the breaks in the loops are indicated by a dotted line pointing back to the original call location (the ones marked "unfulfilled")?

There is also an "Opt" box that handles the "unfulfilled" condition.

Comment: Can anyone make any sense of this diagram in less than 10 minutes? UML is insane. Even more insane is that real programmers know how to use it. +1 for your eclecticism :)

Comment: To be fair, I don't use UML all that much, and when I do, it's "on the back of a napkin."  I'm not slavish about style, and I don't use most of the features that UML provides, but I think that's true of most pragmatic software developers.